# ASP.NET CORE doesn't list all installed SDKs on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, sdk

I recently installed three different SDK versions of ASP.NET CORE on my linux Ubuntu, i have projects with versions **2.2.207**, **3.1.421** and **6.0.302**, if i try to run these projects, all of then run correctly, but if i execute a command **dotnet --list-sdks**, it only list a 6.0.302 SDK, and if i try to create a new ASP.NET CORE project, it doesn't appear the 3.1 and 2.2 version, what can i do to list all SDKs versions?

I Installed these SDKs with **dotnet-install.sh** [dotnetinstall scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script)

[image]

[image]